# Addressfield autocomplete language independent or restrict user language when storing information

Tags: views, ajax, google-maps, entities

I've got address field autocomplete for storing user city only but when entering information it stores them language specific e.g. if ones enter

*София, България*

it's not the same as

*Sofia, Bulgaria*

Although both stores the same latitude and longitude.
In database they are stored as:

```
a:4:{s:8:"latitude";s:10:"42.6977082";s:9:"longitude";s:18:"23.321867500000053";s:4:"zoom";s:0:"";s:17:"formatted_address";s:28:"София, България";}
```

```
a:4:{s:8:"latitude";s:10:"42.6977082";s:9:"longitude";s:18:"23.321867500000053";s:4:"zoom";s:0:"";s:17:"formatted_address";s:15:"Sofia, Bulgaria";}
```

As I need a view with exposed filter for filtering users by city this results in showing two kind of results one for those stored in Bulgarian and one for those stored in English.

I need a way to restrict user entered data to be stored only in one language or to unify results based on lat/lon